# Generalization in Database

Tags: database, database-design

I Need to Design a database for a system where there's **Customers** and **Vendors** but they both are related to entity called **Users** where every user is either a customer or a vendor .
the problem is that **Vendors** are related to other entities that **Customers** aren't .
so how can I design such a database ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is not fit for SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: This is called the Party Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other entities will store the ID of the Vendor as a foreign key. And Vendors and Customers are not going to be in the same table anyway<sup>*</sup>, so it's not like the two have IDs that might be used at the same time for that.

Also, to add, the Foreign Key you require for User could be managed as an add/edit trigger if your DB of choice allows it. That way you can make sure that the Vendor id used for those related entities isn't a User ID linked to Customers. (`...WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM users WHERE customer = TRUE)`)

<sup>*</sup> Customers and Vendors have different properties/fields so shouldn't be in the same table.

Comment: They could share a common set of information, such as login info into a web site.

Comment: but the problem is that there're times when I need to link both of Vendors & Customers to the same table ..
let's say I want to join Vendors to a table called ( Accounts )
and I Want to join Customers to the same table ( Accounts )
BUT , every record of ACCOUNTS Should be linked to ONE User ( Either a Customer or Vendor ) ! How can I solve this matter ?

Comment: I am assuming that when you join the `Accounts` table either a) Vendors and Customers are NOT linked in the same record - so the `entityID` field in Accounts can be a Customer or Vendor - in that case, use the `userID` and you have a field for `customer = TRUE/FALSE`. OR b) if Vendors and Customers are linked in the same record, then the obvious `vendorID` and `customerID` fields (but I don't think this is what you were asking, so use option a.)

Comment: @Marvo: Yes, that's where the `users` table in my example comes in. FYI, in your structure, without triggers for two tables `vendor` and `customer`, there is no way to ensure that the `user.userID` doesn't get repeated in both tables. Based on the requirement like `Accounts` table where either one could be linked, the `users.userID` field would used in `Accounts` anyway. (Other tables may exclusively have a `vendorID` or `customerID` field if they'll only deal with one of those.)

Answer (score 0):

You could have Vendors and Customers have a relationship to a User table.

```
user
===========
userId
name

vendor
===========
vendorId
companyName
userId

customer
===========
customerId
source
userId
```

Then you can link to both customers and vendors from the same table, yet they can still share the same common data in the user table.  In fact, a customer could also be a vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be generalized as follows:  how do I express subclasses in relational tables?

For the generic answer, see this:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/class-table-inheritance/info